# Is a measure, which is equivalent to a discrete measure, also discrete?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal F)$ be a measurable space. Define a probability measure by $\mathbb P=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\alpha_k\delta_{\omega_k},$ where $(\omega_k)_{k\in\mathbb N}\subseteq \Omega,$ $\delta_\omega$ denotes the point measure at $\omega,$ and $(\alpha_k)_{k\in\mathbb N}\subset (0,1)$ with $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\alpha_k=1.$ Let $\mathbb P'$ be a measure, which is equivalent to $\mathbb P.$ Is then $\mathbb P'$ of the form $$\mathbb P'=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\beta_k\delta_{\omega'_k}$$ for some sequence $(\omega'_k)_{k\in\mathbb N}\subseteq\Omega$?

Comment: After Davide Giraudo's answer, I realized that I only want to show that $\mathbb P'=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\beta_k\delta_{\omega'_k}$ for some sequence $(\omega'_k)_{k\in\mathbb N}\subseteq\Omega,$ i.e. that $\mathbb P'$ also must be a discrete measure.

Answer (score 1):

The complement of $S:=\{\omega_k, k\in\mathbb N\}$ has a null $\mathbb P$-measure, hence it is also the case for the $\mathbb P'$. Therefore, $\mathbb P'$ is supported by $S$. This works if $S$ belongs to $\mathcal F$.

Since $\mathbb P$ and $\mathbb P'$ are equivalent, there exists a positive  function $f$ such that $\mathbb P'=f\mathbb P$, hence 
$\mathbb P'=\sum\limits_{k\in\mathbb N}f(\omega_k)\delta_{\omega_k}$.

Comment: Since points are not necessarily measurable,  the set $S$ does not have to be measurable too, right? So how can we say that $S$ has $\mathbb P$-measures null...

Comment: In general not, but if each $\{\omega_k\}$ is measurable it will be OK.

Comment: Since I am working on a general measurable space, I am not sure if your conclusion is still true...I would like to know if one can conclude this generally

Comment: You are right. See edit.

Comment: Very nice! Actually, what I only need is to show that $\mathbb P'$ is a discrete measure too...would you mind if I change the question to that? And do you think that the statement is then true?

Comment: You can use Radon-Nykodim theorem.

Comment: In the example of the second paragraph, I would say that the support is Omega for P and for P'.

Comment: @Did I edited in order to clear this inaccuracy and answer the question in the edited version of the question.